# While implementing socket io in next js how can i access the io object on the server without having to recreate it

Tags: next.js, socket.io

My first time implementing socket.io. I want to send a message to my connected client from the server. Here is my current implementation.

**socket.ts (/pages/api/socket)**

```
import {
  ClientToServerEvents,
  NextApiResponseWithSocket,
  ServerToClientEvents,
} from "@/types/socket-types";
import type { NextApiRequest } from "next";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

export const handler = async (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponseWithSocket
) => {
  if (!res.socket.server.io) {
    console.log("First use, starting socket.io");

    const io = new Server<ClientToServerEvents, ServerToClientEvents>(
      res.socket.server,
      { path: "/api/socket", addTrailingSlash: false }
    );

    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      socket.broadcast.emit("userServerConnection");
      socket.on("hello", (msg) => {
        socket.emit("hello", msg);
      });
      socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("A user disconnected");
        socket.broadcast.emit("userServerDisconnection", socket.id);
      });
    });

    res.socket.server.io = io;
  } else {
    console.log("socket.io already running");
  }
  res.end();
};

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default handler;
```

The above file is the one to setup the connection. *supposedly i dont know what im doing please mention if you see a bug.*

**stk-push-callback.ts (/pages/api/stk-push-callback)**
This is my callback URL. From this url is where i want to send a  "notification" to the client who has just made the payment.

code:

```
import {
  ClientToServerEvents,
  NextApiResponseWithSocket,
  ServerToClientEvents,
} from "@/types/socket-types";
import { NextApiRequest } from "next";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const POST = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponseWithSocket) => {
  const text = req.body;
  // const parsed: STKPushSuccessfulCallbackBody | STKPushErrorCallbackBody =
  //   JSON.parse(text);

  const io = new Server<ClientToServerEvents, ServerToClientEvents>(
    res.socket.server,
    { path: "/api/socket", addTrailingSlash: false }
  );

  if (text.Body.stkCallback.ResultCode === 0) {
    console.log("success", text);
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      socket.emit("paymentSuccess", { message: "payment success" });
    });
  } else {
    console.log("error", text);
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      socket.emit("paymentError", { message: "payment error" });
    });
  }
};

export default POST;
```

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**
You do notice in both files i create a new io object as in the below line.

```
 const io = new Server<ClientToServerEvents, ServerToClientEvents>(
      res.socket.server,
      { path: "/api/socket", addTrailingSlash: false }
    );
```

I dont know why that looks problematic. Shouldnt i use the one in socket.ts because that is the oone on which the client is connected?

If so how can i achieve that? I can`t export it from the file in which it was created right? Or can i?

I tried to crate a new socket client using chatGPT but i don`t have access to the app in NEXTJS so that couldnt work.

Here is how i send a connection req from the client.

client.tsx

```
export let socket: Socket<ServerToClientEvents, ClientToServerEvents> | null =
  null;

const Client = () => {
  const pathName = usePathname();
  //more code

  useEffect(() => {
    socketInitializer();
    return () => {
      if (socket) {
        socket.disconnect();
        socket = null;
      }
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const socketInitializer = async () => {
    if (!socket) {
      await fetch("/api/socket");

      socket = io({ path: "/api/socket" });

      socket.on("connect", () => {
        console.log("connected");
      });

      socket.on("hello", (msg: string) => {
        console.log("hello", msg);
      });

      socket.on("userServerConnection", () => {
        console.log("a user connected (client)");
      });

      socket.on("userServerDisconnection", (socketId: string) => {
        console.log(socketId);
      });

      socket.on("paymentSuccess", (msg) => {
        toast.success(msg.message);
        downloadAllFiles(project?.id!);
      });

      socket.on("paymentError", (msg) => {
        console.log("here");
        toast.error(msg.message);
      });
    }
  };
// you get it :)
```

So how do i do that?

Here is the type definitions if you need them.

**types**

```
import type { Server as HTTPServer } from "http";
import type { Socket as NetSocket } from "net";
import type { NextApiResponse } from "next";
import type { Server as IOServer } from "socket.io";

export interface SocketServer extends HTTPServer {
  io?: IOServer | undefined;
}

export interface SocketWithIO extends NetSocket {
  server: SocketServer;
}

export interface NextApiResponseWithSocket extends NextApiResponse {
  socket: SocketWithIO;
}

export interface ServerToClientEvents {
  userServerConnection: () => void;
  hello: (msg: string) => void;
  paymentSuccess: (msg: { message: string }) => void;
  paymentError: (msg: { message: string }) => void;
  userServerDisconnection: (socketId: string) => void;
}

export interface ClientToServerEvents {
  hello: (msg: string) => void;
  userServerConnection: () => void;
  userServerDisconnection: (socketId: string) => void;
}
```

*please note. I honestly don`t know wtf im doing. I f you have time you can help spot the bugs i would be reaally appreciative.*